# Render s3 template with context without actually downloading it?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have my emails HTML on amazon-s3. I got the specific file from amazon-s3 and got its content in a variable. Now I need to render that email content with my context. Is there any way in Django to achieve it? Any built-in functions?

I initially tried downloading that file from s3 but doing that was complete nonsense. So I tried this code of getting only the file content.

```
s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region_name='ap-south-1'
)

response = s3.Object(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
'static/seller_order_invoice_pdf.html').get()

decoded_file = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
render(None, decoded_file, context)
```

Sample Response:

```
['{% load i18n %}', '{% load staticfiles %}', '{% load storefront_urls %}', '{% load template_extra %}', '', '<!doctype html>', '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">', '  <head>', '    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />', '    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />', '    <title>Tax Invoice | {{ business_name }}</title>', '    <style>', '      @media print {', '        thead {display: table-header-group;}', '      }', '    </style>', '  </head>', '  <body style="position: relative;max-width:100%; margin: 0 auto; color: #001028;background: #fff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; padding: 0 15px;" bgcolor="#fff">', '    <div class="signup-emailer">', '      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">', '        <tbody>', '          <tr>', '            <td align="center">', '              <table style="max-width:650px; width:100%; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; background-color: #fff;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">', '                <tbody>', '                  <tr>', '                    <td width="15"></td>', '                    <td>', '                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">', '                        <tbody>', '                          <tr>', '                            <td width="15"></td>', '                            <td height="5"></td>', '                            <td width="15"></td>', '                          </tr>', '                          <tr>', '                            <td width="15"></td>', '                            <td valign="middle" align="center" style="padding:0 15px;">', '                              <a href="http://{{ domain_name }}" target="_blank" style="color: #000; text-decoration: none;">', '                                <h4 style="text-align: center;font-size: 18px;margin: 10px 0;font-weight: bold;">{{ business_name }}</h4>', '                              </a>', '                            </td>', '                            <td width="15"></td>', '                          </tr>', '                          <tr>', '                            <td width="15"></td>', '                            <td align="center" style="font-weight:bold; color:#000; font-size:16px; text-transform:uppercase;">', '                              Tax Invoice', '                            </td>', '                            <td width="15"></td>', '                          </tr>', '                          <tr>', '                            <td width="15"></td>', '                            <td height="10"></td>', '                            <td width="15"></td>', '                          </tr>', '                          <tr>', '                            <td width="15"></td>', '                            <td align="center" style="color: #636363; font-weight: 700;">Thanks for shopping!</td>', '                            <td width="15"></td>', '                          </tr>', '                          <tr>', '
```

I need to render my email content with the context I am passing.

Comment: What does "email content" mean? Do you have an email message in RFC5322 format? That's not valid HTML at all, nor at all likely to be valid UTF-8.

Comment: email content means I had converted all the content of the file in utf-8 format.

Comment: That doesn't clarify it at all really. Could you please [edit] the question to include a sample of the data (probably trimmed down to just give us an idea of the structure)?

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have anything in common with email; perhaps you should clarify the text to better identify it. To me, that looks like a Django template broken up into a list (which is probably fine, I don't know); the `<!doctype ...>` and `<meta ...>` tags look misplaced but might simply be ignored and thus basically harmless.